# Passing resolve result to controller in AngularJS fails

Tags: angularjs

I set up the configuration for my main module in the following way:

```
angular.module('main').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, ConfigProvider)
    {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home',
            {
                templateUrl : ConfigProvider.path.views + '/page/home.html',
                controller : 'PageHomeCtrl',
                resolve : {
                    resolveHomeData : function(ResolveService) { return ResolveService.resolveHome() }
                }
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
);
```

The `ResolveService` takes care of resolving the routes and at the moment is very simple:

```
angular.module('app.resolve').factory('ResolveService', function($q, UserService)
{
    return {
        resolveHome : function()
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            UserService.find('me', function(data)
            {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }, function(data, status)
            {
                deferred.reject(data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

This instead is the `PageHomeCtrl`:

```
angular.module('app.ui.page.home').controller('PageHomeCtrl', function($q, $scope, UserService, resolveHomeData)
{

});
```

As you can see I'm injecting the `resolveHomeData` in it but I get the following error from AngularJS:

```
Unknown provider: resolveHomeDataProvider
```

Why is `resolveHomeData` not injected correctly into my controller?

I'm concatenating everything with a Gulp script and I'm including all AngularJS files in the following order:

1. Modules definitions
2. Modules configurations
3. Providers
4. Controllers
5. Directives
6. Filters
7. Services

Edit:

This is the `main` module definition:

```
angular.module('main',
    [
        'ngRoute',
        'app.config',
        'app.resolve',
        'app.ui.page.index',
        'app.ui.page.home',
        'app.ui.modal.login'
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: deleted my answer before due to your comment.

AngularJS thinks your `resolveHomeData` is a provider/service instead of the resolved data. This happens because the controller is also defined in the HTML by accident, thus having twice the declaration for the controller: once in the HTML, and once in the config.

Remove the HTML and it should work.

Comment: `app.resolve` is already in the main module definition. I'm updating the question with the `main` module definition. Also I can't put the service inside a variable because i'm putting all my modules inside anonymous functions to avoid collisions.

Comment: In my case the service is injected into the resolve function and I can tell you that it's working because the service is sending requests to the server.

Comment: @siannone I see. Then for some reason Angular thinks your parameter is a provider/service instead of the resolved variable. I'll try to see why.

Comment: @siannone Ok got a thought: in the HTML are you also defining the `ng-controller="PageHomeCtrl"` by accident ?

Comment: You're right! This is basically the HTML `<div ng-controller="PageHomeCtrl">
    Welcome!
</div>` Do I need to remove the `ng-controller` directive?

Comment: @siannone Great! Remove it and it should work. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you! You've helped me so much!